Access BLoC Instance outside of build meth
I am creating a Stateful Widget and use BLoC as State Management and I want to add video_player package on it. In the video_player documentation, they use late initialize controller and do init state and directly pass the video link:
late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/Butterfly-209.mp4');

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}));
    _controller.play();
  }

But, my BLoC value only could be accessed in block of Widget build function as follows:
BlocBuilder<AudioPlayerBloc, AudioPlayerState>(
builder: (context, state) {
return Text(state.videoLink)}),

My Question:

How can I init the VideoPlayerController.asset link to state.videoLink in a correct way? Is there a way to not utilize the initState and use the BLoC State instead ?
Continuing to previous question, How can I save the VideoPlayerController variable into the BLoC in a correct way so I could access it in the BlocBuilder by accessing the state.videoPlayerController and use the method of it , such as .play()? I already tried this by creating the variable in the BLoC State and access in BlocBuilder, but still it doesn't run properly.


add this file to your project

video_player_widget.dart

add this code to 'video_player_widget' file :-
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';


    class VideoPlayerWidget extends StatefulWidget {
      final String videoUrl;


      const VideoPlayerWidget(
          {super.key,
          required this.videoUrl});

      @override
      State<VideoPlayerWidget> createState() =>
          VideoPlayerWidgetState();
    }

    class VideoPlayerWidgetState extends State<VideoPlayerWidget> {
      late VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
   

      @override
      void initState() {

        setController();
        super.initState();
      }



      @override
      void dispose() {
        videoPlayerController.dispose();

        super.dispose();
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return (videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized)
            ? VideoPlayer(videoPlayerController)
            : SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
      }

      Future setController() async {
        try {

            videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
                Uri.parse(widget.videoUrl),
                videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(mixWithOthers: true));

          await videoPlayerController.initialize();

        } on Exception catch (e, s) {
          print("Video Url is Not Set $e $s");
        }
        setState(() {});
      }


    }

then in Your Bloc Provider :-
BlocBuilder<AudioPlayerBloc, AudioPlayerState>(
builder: (context, state) {
return VideoPlayerWidget(videoUrl: "assets/Butterfly-209.mp4");
}),

